# Trying to make a gif in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm approximating functions with Fourier Series and I would like to make, hopefully in a simple way, an animated gif of the different approximations. With a `for` and `plt.savefig` commands I generate the different frames for the gif but I haven't been able to animate them. The idea is to obtain something like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [matplotlib.animation](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html).

**EDIT**

I'm going to show you how to plot even powers of x like `x^2`, `x^4` and so on. take a look at following example :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# Setting up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 1000))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization method: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation method.  This method will be called sequentially
pow_ = 2
def animate(i):
    global pow_
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
    y = x**pow_
    pow_+=2
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=10, interval=200, blit=True)

# if you want to save this animation as an mp4 file, uncomment the line bellow
# anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Selcuk I've edited my answer and explained an example, teşekkürler abi :)